# moving file from desktop to Oracle directory

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created a directory in Oracle via the command create directory. The directory is called temp. I have a file located on:

G:\Documents\SO\Content\102010 Stack Overflow\test.xml

that I want to put in this directory. How can I do this via a SQL statement?

Comment: If "G:\Documents\SO\Content\102010 Stack Overflow\" is a directory on your local computer to which Oracle Server does not have access, then it is impossible in SQL or PL/SQL.

Comment: Can't you just copy the file between your computer and the server (for example using SCP)?

Comment: Well then how can I move a file in my local machine into a remote Oracle database directory..

Comment: You're saying just use a regular FTP?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle's directory feature is not meant to enable file transfer from a client to the server.  If you want to put a file there for Oracle's use (e.g. as an external table), then the standard way that is done is for the dba or system administrator to move the file into the appropriate directory on the server; or for them to grant you access via standard file-sharing means.